# Simple POST request using jQuery leads to unexpected redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, browser

I've got a few similar POST request on a website. In one case, the request is working (data is stored on the server), but then, there's an unexpected redirect. I send/receive data using jQuery. On the backend, I use the PHP framework Laravel.

Let's say I'm on `myapp.dev/clients/123`. Then I click the `store-data-button` and data is sent to/received from the server (Let's assume `$('#resubmission_note').val() === 'abc'`):

```
// AJAX request
$('#store-data-button').on('click', function() {
    let ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        url:  '/resubmissions',
        type: 'POST',
        data:  {
            // An integer, some text, and a date
            'client_id': $('#id').html(),
            'resubmission_note': $('#resubmission_note').val(),
            'resubmission_due_date': $('#resubmission_due_date').val()
        }
    });

    ajaxRequest.done(function(returned_id) {
        // Removed all code here for testing. Browser still redirecting.
    });
});
```

But then the browser is redirected to `myapp.dev/clients/123?resubmission_note=abc`.

The network tab in Chrome devtools says

Name:123?resubmission_note=abc
Status: 200
Type: document
initiator: Other

There's data appended in the URL, that should only be the case with GET request, AFAIK. I checked whether some other JavaScript code might interfere, but couldn't find `store-data-button` or `resubmission_note` in any unexpected files.

Any advice on how to fix the problem or how to debug it?

Comment: Sounds like the button is in a `<form>`, and it gets submitted (a form's default parameters are `method="GET"` and `action=""`, which is the current URL. Try adding `return false;` at the end of the click handler function. Or, if you're using `<button>`, add `type="button"`, because the default type is `"submit"`.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG What an unnecessary mistake, I actually still had <form> tags in my code. Laravel doesn't allow the GET request to be processed on the server, I overlooked that this doesn't prevent the browser from sending a request...